Error when building MariaDB ODBC Connector
Currently, I am building MariaDB ODBC Connector with version 3.1.20

ma_statement.c:1738:22: error: ‘MYSQL_BIND’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql_bind’} has no member named ‘flags’
Stmt->result[i].flags|= MADB_BIND_DUMMY;

Please explain above this issue and how to fix it
I search but not find the solution!

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Which Connector/C implementation and version are you linking to? Or is 3.1.20 the C/C version. If so which ODBC version. Which compiler/OS?

I am building from the source in the link below
https://dlm.mariadb.com/browse/odbc_connector/87/1930/
compiler is: cmake version 3.20.2
OS is RH8.5
and using MYSQL_BIND of mysql-devel x86_64 8.0.36-1.module+el8.9.0+21207+6c20cb3d rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms

You need MariDB Connector/C headers and library in order to build the Connector/ODBC from source package. You can found here https://mariadb.com/docs/server/connect/programming-languages/c/install/ how to install it.
Maybe it would be easier to build from repository checkout - it would automatically pull and build the required version of the Connector/C. Something like
git clone https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-odbc.git
cd mariadb-connector-odbc
git checkout 3.1.20
cd ..
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ../mariadb-connector-odbc/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCONC_WITH_UNIT_TESTS=Off -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DWITH_SSL=OPENSSL
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo


The code of MYSQL_BIND mysql-devel x86_64 8.0.36-1.module+el8.9.0+21207+6c20cb3d rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
typedef struct MYSQL_BIND {
    unsigned long *length; 
    bool *is_null;         
    void *buffer;         
    bool *error;
    unsigned char *row_ptr; 
    void (*store_param_func)(NET *net, struct MYSQL_BIND *param);
    void (*fetch_result)(struct MYSQL_BIND *, MYSQL_FIELD *, unsigned char **row);
    void (*skip_result)(struct MYSQL_BIND *, MYSQL_FIELD *, unsigned char **row);
    unsigned long buffer_length;
    unsigned long offset;            
    unsigned long length_value;       
    unsigned int param_number;        
    unsigned int pack_length;          
    enum enum_field_types buffer_type; 
    bool error_value;                 
    bool is_unsigned;                 
    bool long_data_used;               
    bool is_null_value;               
    void *extension;
 } MYSQL_BIND;

I don't see flags property of MYSQL_BIND structure. So why is the code of MariaDB ODBC Connector with version 3.1.20 called that?

See Lawrin's answer: You installed MySQL client library instead of MariaDB Connector/C.
